# Make app working on ultra hd computers

Tags: virtual-machine, 4k-resolution

I have a ultra HD computer and some apps don't work well with this resolution (*too small text, buttons, etc*)

[image]

I tried to run them on a virtual machine but it has the same problem. I set the resolution of the VM like 1920 x 1080 or other, but in this case the VM is too small, and so the app.

Have you got any solution to make the app working well on my computer or with a VM ? I don't want to do it on another pc.

Comment: Pretty sure that VirtualBox has an option to scale the guest display, which could work...

Comment: I tried with VMWare, but not with virtualbox. Thanks I'll try

Comment: **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display** would also possibly fix this issue. Although it would make everything else bigger too so doing this in Virtual box would be better.

Comment: `I don't want to do it on another pc.` - Another monitor? :)

Comment: haha, no I can't neither.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VitualBox you can scale the display up, this sounds like it could solve your problem.

Once the VM is up and running go to the menu at the top and select **View**. At the bottom of that menu should be a **Scale Factor** submenu. From there you can select 200%.

You might need the Guest Additions installed, I'm not too sure.